# How do I create a usage plan with the throttle and quota limits for the new HTTP APIs?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

How do I create a usage plan with the throttle and quota limits for the new HTTP APIs?

Quoting from the post below:

> They come with standard API Gateway functionality such as throttling, metrics, and logging capabilities

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/amazon-api-gateway-offers-faster-cheaper-simpler-apis-using-http-apis-preview/

However, the UI for REST APIs doesn't show usage plan tab. The cli tool throws an error when you use the api id for the rest api id:

```
aws --region us-west-2 apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id api-id-goes-here
An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the GetResources operation: Invalid API identifier specified 000000000000:xxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP APIs don't support usage plans and API keys as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html).

Also, to run the above CLI command you will have to use [apigatewayv2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigatewayv2/index.html) to get information on HTTP APIs. The API V1 namespace represents REST APIs and API V2 represents WebSocket APIs and the new HTTP APIs.